# Which C# containers are contiguous and which are node-based?

Tags: c#, list, containers

In Item 1 of *Effective STL*, Herb Sutter makes a distinction between contiguous and node-based containers. Vectors, strings, and deques are contiguous, while linked lists and associative containers are node-based. This is useful for performance considerations (speed of insertion or deletion from the start, middle, or end, iteration, large memory allocation considerations, etc.)

In particular, I'm interested in `List<T>` and a list such as: `BaseList : CollectionBase, ITypedList`.

I heard somewhere that `List<T>` is more like a `std::vector<T>` than a linked list. So are both these C# containers contiguous? What node containers are available besides `LinkedList<T>`? Is there a comparison on MSDN somewhere, perhaps?

Comment: You can look at the documentation for each of the collections you are interested in to get an overview of the data structures, to which you should be able to determine which are contiguous and which are node based.

Comment: @Servy I did check the documentation first, of course. It was not as explicit as I would like.

Comment: Then you'd need to be much more specific about which data structure you're curious about, what you *do* know about its implementation, and what you *don't* understand about its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way to check is by browsing the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

For instance, here's the code for [`List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs), which states in a comment at the top of the file:

> ** Purpose: Implements a generic, dynamically sized list as an 
>   **          array.

Answer (score 2):

There is a table in this article that lists which containers are contiguous (scroll down):

http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

Excerpt:

*The List is a basic contiguous storage container. Some people may call this a vector or dynamic array. Essentially it is an array of items that grow once its current capacity is exceeded. Because the items are stored contiguously as an array, you can access items in the List by index very quickly. However inserting and removing in the beginning or middle of the List are very costly because you must shift all the items up or down as you delete or insert respectively. However, adding and removing at the end of a List is an amortized constant operation - O(1). Typically List is the standard go-to collection when you don't have any other constraints, and typically we favor a List even over arrays unless we are sure the size will remain absolutely fixed.*

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It does not mention the abstract CollectionBase, though. From what I can tell on MSDN, it seems like it would be array-backed as well.

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> The List class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class. It
>   implements the IList generic interface by using an array whose size
>   is dynamically increased as required.

So, a `List<T>` is contiguous.

Comment: So `List<T>` is backed by an array? Which would mean it's contiguous.